# Rails 3: I have controller name and action and need to get path and http verb for it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In rails 3.2 I need to get **path** and **http verb** of rails endpoint by *controller name* and *action name*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please from terminal of your computer write `rake routes | grep matching_controller_name` this will show the path of the related matching routes of that path with http-verb and action and controller.

Comment: What if don't use `rake routes`?

Comment: do you want to have this situation for showing in the webpage or something? Like documentation generation?

Comment: I need rails generator for rspec request test for given endpoint.

Comment: for creating custom generator please take a look here http://beerlington.com/blog/2013/06/23/creating-a-custom-rspec-generator/
and if you still want to automate of getting the endpoint and http-verb and controller and action then you might have to make File read write operation from the routes file. Hope this helps.